# Efficiently find a sequence within a buffer

Tags: c, arrays, embedded

So I have a buffer that I am filling with a frame that has a maximum of 1200 bytes and is variably sized. I know the frame is complete when I get a tail sequence that is always the same and doesn't occur otherwise. So I am trying to find how to most efficiently detect that tail sequence. This is embedded so ideally the fewer function calls and data structures I use the better.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
//I am reading off of a circular buffer so this is checking that I still have unread bytes  
while (cbuf_last_written_index != cbuf_last_read_index) {
    buffer[frame_size] = circular_buffer[cbuf_last_read_index];
    //this function does exactly what it says and just maintains circular buffer correctness
    increment_cbuf_read_index_count();
    frame_size++;

    //TODO need to make this more efficient
    int i;
    uint8_t sync_test_array[TAIL_SYNC_LENGTH] = {0};
    //this just makes sure I have enough in the frame to even bother checking the tail seq
    if (frame_size > TAIL_SYNC_LENGTH) { 
        for (i = 0; i < TAIL_SYNC_LENGTH; i++) {
            //sets the test array equal to the last TAIL_SYNC_LENGTH elements the buffer 
            sync_test_array[i] = buffer[(frame_size - TAIL_SYNC_LENGTH) + i];
        }
        if (sync_test_array == tail_sequence_array) {                     
            //I will toggle a pin here to notify that the frame is complete

            //get out of the while loop because the following bytes are part of the next frame
            break;
        }
     }
     //end efficiency needed area              
}
```

So basically for each new byte that is added to the frame I am checking the last x bytes (will probably actually be ~8) to see if they are the tail sequence. Can you think of a better way to do this?

Comment: It would be faster to only examine the most-recently read byte to see if it furthers your match.  E.g., if the last 3 bytes read match the first three of your pattern, then the next byte needs to match byte 4 of the pattern, etc.  Are you only able to read a single byte into your buffer at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement it as a state machine.

If your tail sequence is 1,2,5, the psuedo code would be:

```
switch(current_state) {
 IDLE: next_state = ONE_SEEN if new_byte == 1 else next-state = IDLE
 ONE_SEEN: next_state = TWO_SEEN if new_byte == 2 else next_state = IDLE
 TWO_SEEN: next_state = TERMINATE if new_byte == 5 else next_state = IDLE
}
```

Comment: It's basically an expansion of caskey's solution.  Using a finite state machine is the most common way of recognizing a sequence of values over time.